# zend framework 2 change date format in form

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to change date format in ZF2 application. I have tried this :

```
         $this->add(array(
         'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Date',
         'name' => 'date_of_entry',
         'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Datum unosa',
                 'format' => 'd-m-Y'
         ),
         'attributes' => array(
                 'class' => 'my_input',
                 'min' => '01-01-1970',
                 'step' => '1', 
         )
     ));
    $this->get('date_of_entry')->setFormat('d-m-Y');
```

In view I am getting mm\dd\yyyy format, what is wrong?

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to change the format in zf2 application or filter the format of a form element?

Comment: I want to change how user will see date in application. Now format looks like mm\dd\yyyy but when form is submited in database date format is Y-m-d. I want to change only date format in view part of application and to keep Y-m-d format in database.

Comment: On view where does this format mm\dd\yyyy come from? is the user setting this date or is this value already set?

Comment: cant you just do it like this? $oldDate = "2014-05-27";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));? then if you add this value to the form the date will be d-m-Y.

Comment: I have fixed this with changing the Chrome language. In default english language, date format for HTML 5 date field is mm\dd\yyyy. When the language is changed, date format is also changed. In backend date format remained in Y-m-d format. Looks like Chrome automaticaly converts date from local format to standard Y-m-d format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t set the format within the array – it has to be via a **setFormat()** call.

I think you need to remove this `'format' => 'd-m-Y'`

```
$this->add(array(
         'type' => 'ZendFormElementDateTime',
         'name' => 'date_of_entry',
         'options' => array(
                 'label' => 'Datum unosa',
              ),
         'attributes' => array(
                 'class' => 'my_input',
                 'min' => '01-01-1970',
                 'step' => '1', 
        )
    )
);
$this->get('date_of_entry')->setFormat('d-m-Y');
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I have fixed this with changing the Chrome language. In default english language, date format for HTML 5 date field is mm\dd\yyyy. When the language is changed, date format is also changed. In backend date format remained in Y-m-d format. Looks like Chrome automaticaly converts date from local format to standard Y-m-d format